Unable to override the Login component
I have created a new application in spartacus V4.3.
I am able to load the login page.
What I want is override the email validation and add a custom validation so that I will allow different input to pass through and login with credential, but I am not able to find the exact file where I can change this. I tried searching for "login-form.component.html" or the TS file but I could not find the code or script where the LOGIN form loads.
Can anyone please help me on this? I want to override the validation on the user id input field.
Early reply would be appreciated, Thanks.

Please don't add tag's in the question's title - That's what the tag-system is for... Furthermore: Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?
